# Alerting on application log errors k8s

Tags: kubernetes, logging, microservices, kibana, alert

I have a .NET 6 microservice running in a container hosted on a k8s cluster.
I use Prometheus to collect my application and cluster metrics and based on some metrics criteria, I have defined alerts in Prometheus alert manager and configured it to send messages in Slack in case of alerts.

In case of a handled application exception, we log it with log level as **ERROR**.

We use **Elastic APM** and **Kibana** to collect and display application metrics and logs.

But in case of an application error, even though there are ERROR messages present in the logs, there is no way to alert the development team about these errors (unless someone goes and explicitly looks at the logs).
Is there any way (any available tool or custom setup) to **generate alerts whenever there is an ERROR in my application log?**

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/logs-threshold-alert.html

Comment: yep I was exactly looking into this. Have you used this @HarshManvar

Comment: No sorry personally i have not used that.